# Broadcast receiver not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement a Broadcast message receiver in Xamarin Forms but unable to receive any message, I am not sure what is going wrong,Below is my Main Activity Code

```
[Activity(Label = "HeloApp.Android", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());
            Connector.Instance.Initialize(this, "151265380086941117", "E862D6D7D70ED2C3729CB24BC3AB40753A52EAB0");
            MeasurementReceiver heartRateRec = new MeasurementReceiver();
            RegisterReceiver(heartRateRec, new IntentFilter("com.worldgn.connector.HR_MEASUREMENT"));
        }

    }

    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.worldgn.connector.HR_MEASUREMENT" })]
    public class MeasurementReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action.Equals("com.worldgn.connector.HR_MEASUREMENT"))
            {
                var heartRate = intent.GetStringExtra("HR_MEASUREMENT");
            }
        }
    }
```

And below is how i am initiating the Broadcast receiver from the xamarin forms side. I am not sure how the broadcast receiver will work in the given scenario cause i am doing it for the very first time.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class BLEDevices : ContentPage
    {
        public BLEDevices()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        private void SearchBLE_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connector.Instance.Scan(new DeviceScanCallBack());
        }

        private void Disconnect_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connector.Instance.UnbindDevice();
        }
    }

    public class DeviceScanCallBack : Java.Lang.Object, IScanCallBack
    {
        public void OnLedeviceFound(DeviceItem p0)
        {
            Connector.Instance.Connect(p0);
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Information", "Device connected successfully.", "Cancel");

            //Here i am trying to initiate the broadcast receiver
            Connector.Instance.MeasureHR();
        }

        public void OnPairedDeviceNotFound()
        {
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Warning", "Please disconnect the device first.", "OK");
        }

        public void OnScanFinished()
        {

        }

        public void OnScanStarted()
        {

        }
    }
```

What i am trying to achieve is to just hit the OnReceive method on debug mode and that will solve all my issue.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am initiating the Broadcast receiver from the xamarin forms side.

It means that you want use native API(Android platform API [`SendBroadcast`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/broadcast-receivers/)), is it right? If it is right, in `xamarin.Android` you can use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to achieve it.

Four steps:

1.Define interface in [PCL](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/) which you have called as `xamarin forms side`:

```
   public interface ISend
    {
        void Send();
    }
```

2.Implementation Android Platform:

```
class SendImpl : ISend
{
    public void Send()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.worldgn.connector.HR_MEASUREMENT");
        intent.PutExtra("HR_MEASUREMENT","value");
        Forms.Context.SendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

3.Use `DependencyService` to Register, add this above the namespace:

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(SendImpl))]
```

4.Call to `DependencyService` in PCL, then you will achieve `OnReceive`:

```
public void OnLedeviceFound(DeviceItem p0)
{
    Connector.Instance.Connect(p0);
    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Information", "Device connected successfully.", "Cancel");

    //Here i am trying to initiate the broadcast receiver
    DependencyService.Get<ISend>().Send();
    Connector.Instance.MeasureHR();
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the interface as you have suggested here but still something is missing.

Comment: What about put `RegisterReceiver` above `Init(this, bundle)`